# How to declare mongodb collection with JSDoc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webstorm, jsdoc

Currently I am using WebStorm and hove something like

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(DB) {
    this.DB = DB;
  }
  doSomething() {
    await this.DB.findOne(...);
  }
}
```

After I connect the **MongoClient** from the **mongodb** driver, I use the collection into a MyClass instance:

```
const actions = new MyClass(client.db(mainDB).collection(mainDBCollection));
```

**client** is response of `mongodb.MongoClient.connect()`

The WebStrom shows a notification:

```
Unresolved function or method `insertOne()` in the doSomething function of MyClass
```

How to declare in JSDoc that the DB in MyClass is a instance of the `collection()` function which I get from the mongodb client, so that WebStorm can recognize the functions used in the this.DB/mongo collection?